# Documents folder copied to another computer has strange behaviour

Tags: windows

I am moving to a new computer at work. I copied my Documents folder (C:\Users\myname\Documents) from the old computer to a storage area reserved for my use on the company network. Then I renamed it to "old-computer-name backup". Then I copied it (the folder itself) into the root of the Documents folder on the new computer.

When it arrived on the new computer, I noticed that it did not have the name I gave it, but rather it was called "Documents" again. I renamed it a second time, and it retained the new name. Then I copied it and pasted it within the same directory. I now have two directories in the same place that have the same name in Windows Explorer. If I list folders in that directory from the command line however, the command line tells me that they are called "Documents" and "Documents - Copy".

What has happened to this directory and why doesn't it behave like normal directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hidden `desktop.ini` file within the directory tells Explorer to display it under a different name. Specifically, it's the `LocalizedResourceName=` parameter, which usually points to a string resource stored in a .dll file.

(EXE/DLL files can store multiple localized copies of a resource, so Windows will automatically get the resource for the *current OS language*, allowing the "standard" directories to reflect OS language changes without having to physically rename them and invalidate all existing paths and shortcuts.)

You can delete the whole desktop.ini file (if you don't mind losing the custom icon which is also set via the same file), or edit it to remove just the LocalizedResourceName= parameter.

It might be enough to just remove the "Read Only" (and/or "System") attribute from the directory, as Explorer only looks at desktop.ini files if the directory has at least one of these attributes.